# Python: Selenium Driver find_elements_by_xpath: Issue

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I want to **extract Elements from various webpages** by using the selenium driver package. I identify target elements by their texts, using `find_elements_by_xpath`. Although I thought I was able to solve issues with "*whitespaces*","*breaks*" etc., the following **element is NOT found by my code**, unfortunately.

This is the **element** that I am trying to find by using its text:

```
x = """<p align="left"><font face="Arial" color="#439539" size="5">Compensation
Discussion<br>&amp; Analysis</font></p>"""
```

This is a **screenshot of the original code** of the respective [webpage](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/315189/000120677414000114/deereandco_def14a.htm).

[image]

This is the **Code** that I am currently using to identify elements that contain the text "*Compensation Discussion & Analysis*":

```
searchterm = "Compensation Discussion & Analysis

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(normalize-space(translate(., '\u00A0', ' ')), '" + searchterm + "')]")
```

I know that there might be ways to only include parts of my search-term, such as `starts-with()` and alike. However, I would highly prefer to maintain looking for the entire search-term without splitting it into its components.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have looks good and I would expect `normalize-space()` to work - however, clearly that `<br>` in the middle is an interesting one.

What i can tell you is that the `br` is causing the text to be split into 2 nodes. You actually have `text()` and `text()[2]`.

I've only tried this in chrome, I've not attempted it in selenium yet but try this xpath:

```
//font[contains(normalize-space(concat(text(), ' ', text()[2])),'Compensation Discussion & Analysis')]
```

*(note that i matched this to `font` but you can update as needed)*

This matches your troublesome object and others by full text - which i think is what you're after.

This is how my devtools looks:
[image: devtools]

What could also be useful is you can also add additional items to the concat, even if they don't exist, and still retain the matches:

```
//font[contains(normalize-space(concat(text(), ' ', text()[2], ' ', text[3])),'Compensation Discussion & Analysis')]
```

[image: match with more]

That might mean one identifier to match them all..

---

Final comment - You can see in the middle i join the two nodes WITH A SPACE `concat(text(), ' ', text()[2])` - this is because the text of the nodes is `Compensation Discussion↵& Analysis` - there is no space between "Discussion" and "&" - adding this space increases consistency with the rest of the document.

[image: nodetext]

---

[udpate]

After all the above (which works!) I thought about that "final comment" again....

I looked again and `normalize-space` does work - your text just doesn't have a space before the ampersand...

[image: see here]

Answer (score -1):

**Try this if you are looking for the entire search term on the page:**

```
string=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[19]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[20]/td[1]/font[1]")
print(string.text)
OR
print(string.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

This should do the job!